# How can wait for ajax call end before relooping in foreach?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use Promises but I don't know if in this case, are useful.

```
$.getJSON("url", "data", function(json) {
    json.forEach(function(item) {
        //do something
        $.get("url", "data", function(response) {
            //MAKE SURE THIS BODY IS SOLVED BEFORE RELOOP???
        });
    })
})
```

The only way I found is to use ajax with `async` as `false`.

Is there a way to solve this?

Maybe using Promises for example? I tried to think a way to use Promises in a `foreach` loop but didn't find any solution.

I tried this one:

```
$.getJSON("url", "data", function(json) {
    json.forEach(function(item) {
        //do something
        when($.get("url", "data") {
            //do something
        })).done(function(response){
            //do something
        });
    })
})
```

But it doesn't work. `foreach` always relooped.

Comment: Is there a reason you do not want to use async = false

Comment: Because is deprecated.. even browser notice me that is deprecated

Comment: Could you clarify something? the call $.getJSON("url", "data",...  is it same for the  starting call and each of the calls done using item inside the loop? is data the same ? or each call inside the loop is unique with parameters  based on item during the current loop ?

Comment: I thought that was the whole point of your question. You want to wait for ajax call to finish and do not want to reloop immediately.

Comment: The data is not important.. there is two ajax call that takes data from a server, but the issue is that i cant wait for the get() call ends before reloop.

Comment: @smartdroid you suggest to use async false?

Comment: async option depracated in jquery, but it is still supported. So give it a try. But I think you need to rethink your code to see if you can avoid ajax call within for each.

Comment: Thank you man. I appreciated you help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, you could try re-constructing your data from outer-call to build an array and make use of a function to reflect the looping mechanism and initiate each iteration when the previous inner-call finishes  (successfully or not).

Check this out. Might this be a viable solution for you?

```
$.getJSON("url", "data", function(json) 
{
    var jarray=[];
    var i=0;
    for (var xitem in jsonObj) { 
        //console.log(jsonObj[xitem]);      
        jarray[i++]=jsonObj[xitem];
    }
    nextIteration(jarray,0);
})

function nextIteration(sourceArray, nextIterationIndex)
{
    if(nextIterationIndex<sourceArray.length)
    {
         var item = sourceArray[nextIterationIndex];
            //do something
            $.get("url", "data", function(response) 
            {
                //MAKE SURE THIS BODY IS SOLVED BEFORE RELOOP???
                nextIteration(sourceArray,nextIterationIndex+1);
            });
         
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be of interest to you... As you wish to perform many ajax request one by one in a loop.

Using `await` in an `async` function, you can wait for an ajax resquest to complete before doing the next one.

Below, I used `$.getJSON` in a `for` loop... And the console logs clearly show that each request where made one by one.

The `$.ajax()`, `$.post()`, `$.get()`, `$.getJSON()`, etc. all are returning a promise. So `await` can be used. Instead of using the callback function, you have to assign the `response` to a variable.

as in:

```
let response = await $.getJSON(url);
```

instead of:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(response){...});
```

```
let url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/";
let max = 40;

async function loop() {
  for (i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
    console.log(`=============================== Loop ${i}`);
    let response = await $.getJSON(url + i);
    console.log(response);
    $("#result").append($("<div>").text(response.title));
    console.log(`request ${i} is finished`);
  }
}

loop();
```

-- That is working in [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/ExNaveW?editors=1011) since the SO snippets are squarely blocking any ajax request.